# Convert Resultset to String array

Tags: java, arrays, oracle11g, resultset

I need to Convert My result set to an array of Strings. I am reading Email addresses from the database and I need to be able to send them like:

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, "abc@abc.com,abc@def.com,ghi@abc.com");
```

Here is My code for reading the Email addresses:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        String iphost = "localhost";
        String dbsid = "ASKDB";
        String username = "ASKUL";
        String password = "askul";

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMAIL";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + iphost + ":1521:" + dbsid, username, password);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            String[] arr = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String em = rs.getString("EM_ID");
               arr = em.split("\n");
               for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
                   System.out.println(arr[i]);
               }
            }
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            System.out.println(asd);
        }
    }
}
```

MyOutput is:

```
myemailaddress@abc.com
myotheremail@abc.com
```

I need it like this:

```
myemailaddress@abc.com,myotheremail@abc.com
```

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: To me, it looks like the split is working correctly, but your printed output will ALWAYS be on one line per item in the array ( as you are using System.out.println(). Don't you want to add the results of the split in to a StringBuilder and then System.out.println() that?

Comment: Did' tNnotice that. Yu are right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to get the desired output:

replace these lines

```
String[] arr = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    String em = rs.getString("EM_ID");
    arr = em.split("\n");
    for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

by

```
String arr = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    String em = rs.getString("EM_ID");
    arr = em.replace("\n", ",");
    System.out.println(arr);
}
```

Comment: +1 That seems to be the right approach: rather than fixing the consequences of a split, avoid splitting in the first place! Don't forget to tell the OP that `arr` is no longer an array of strings, but a single string that he wants.

Comment: @codeMan depending of the query, isn't it dangerous to use String, it mights exceed string max length ?

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

Instead use:

```
System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need `arr = em.split("\n");` since you are looping through each row (assuming that 1 row = 1 email address ) you just need this :

```
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {
           arr.add(rs.getString("EM_ID"));
           System.out.println(arr.get(arr.size()-1));
        }
```

Comment: your array is not initialized, and there is now way to retrieve the number of rows returned without iterating over all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly You want to see the output in one line with comma as a separator.
Then instead of

```
System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

Try

```
System.out.print(arr[i]+",");
```

and remove last comma somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

List<String> listEmail = new ArrayList<String>();

while (rs.next()) {
    listEmail.add(rs.getString("EM_ID"));
}
//listEmail,toString() will look like this: [abc@abc.com, abc@def.com]
//So lets replace the brackets and remove the whitspaces
//You can do this in less steps if you want:
String result = listEmail.toString();
       result = result.replace("[", "\"");
       result = result.replace("]", "\"");
       result = result.replace(" ", "");

//your result: "abc@abc.com,abc@def.com"
//If the spaces are e problem just use the string function to remove them
```

Btw you may should use BCC instead of CC in terms of privacy....

Also you should never use 
    SELECT * FROM foo;
Better use
    SELECT EM_ID FROM foo;
This gives you a significant Performance increase in a huge Table, since the ResultSet just consists of the information you really need and use...