# How to use Java ResultSet to convert the results to a String

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am creating a program to remotely connect to a MySQL server and create a `.sql` file without and console access. I am manually doing it to keep track of the progress completed.

In the `.sql` dump files, there is a line(s) which is `INSERT INTO`. I am easily able to make this work with numbers and String objects, but how can I go about doing this with Blobs and Dates?

Is there any way I can use `set.getObject(column);` and convert that into a String which I can place into the `.sql` file?

If not, could I use `set.getMetaData().getColumnType(column)` then compare to each of the many data types? Then from there, how can I convert that into a String to place into the file?

Thank you for any help.

Also, I made this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229056/use-java-to-remotely-backup-a-mysql-database) earlier, and it provides additional information about what I am doing and why.

EDIT: This was marked as a duplicate, but the other answer does not answer my question even in the slightest. This explains how to do it with text datatypes. I need to know how to do it with BLOBS, Date, and all other SQL datatypes.

EDIT 2: I need a solution which will work with all datatypes, not just the ones mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Resultset to String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106914/convert-resultset-to-string-array)

Comment: @sergei it’s not. That will only work with Strings but I need it to work with Blobs, ints, ext.

Comment: You can also use [UNHEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dates use `ResultSet.getDate()` and then convert to String using `SimpleDateFormat` with yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss pattern. Or `ResultSet.getTimestamp()` and create a new Date from the Timestamp time in milliseconds. Then write the date-to-string into the generated SQL file with `CAST('2018-03-12 14:15:16' AS DATETIME)` or `CAST('2018-03-12 14:15:16' AS DATE)`.

For the blobs use `ResultSet.getBinaryStream()` write the stream into a `byte[]` array. Then walk the array and generate an hexadecimal string with two digits per byte. Last put the string into output SQL as `INSERT INTO table (the_blob_column) VALUES (x'89A099D153EF')`

Comment: And ensure that the character encoding of your output files matches the one in the database.

Comment: It does match it. So if I do this, will it work for ALL possible sql datatypes?

Comment: It won't work for all possible SQL types. You will have to carefully convert each possibe type into a string recognized as the type in the SQL statements.

Comment: So there is no simple way to do it? I’ll have to do it for each datatype? Is there a possible library or other methods which can do so?

Comment: @Forseth11 Re "will it work for **ALL possible sql datatypes**", you are now moving the goal posts on your original question which explicitly asked "how can I go about doing this with **Blobs and Dates**". Raise a new post for a new question.

Comment: @skomisa I should have been more clear. I wrote about using `getObject()` to try to use it for all.

Comment: @Forseth11 Then you should update the OP to make it very clear what your question is, since someone has already gone to the trouble of answering the actual question you asked and you have not accepted their answer. Nobody is going to give you an answer that meets your new requirement based on what you asked in the OP.

Comment: @skomisa Changed. What if I use `.getBytes()` and just write that? Will that work?